# Drupal 7 views to display nodes with same taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views

I have an organization page with a taxonomy field. I'd like to create a view of news pages tagged with the same taxonomy term used in this field. I've read and watched several tutorials on relationships and context filters but none of them have helped me create this view. How can this be done?

I'm using Drupal 7.5

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use default value of contextual filter:

[image: Add contextual filter for taxonomy]

[image: Configure filter default value]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the screenshots. Unfortunately it does not seem to work for me. The content type has several taxonomy fields. Do I need to include the one I am wanting to key off of on the fields? The filter criteria?

Comment: If you are using "Content: Has taxonomy term ID" filter (first screenshot) then you may use "Limit terms by vocabulary" in filter settings (second screenshot). As an alternative, you may use any specific filter on your taxonomy field (named like "Field: FIELD_NAME").

This is a general approach which works, in general :) Try to find out where you has an error, if it doesn't work :)